# C# variable issue

Tags: c#

Having problems with some c# variables. Can't figure out what i'm doing wrong. Probably something simple but i've been at it for a bit.

```
public class DataFileLoad
{
    //Public jagged array variables

    public string[][] aConfJag = null;
    public string[][] aPartJag = null;
    public string[][] aTypeJag = null;
    public string[][] aWkshpJag = null;
    public string[][] aWorkJag = null;

    public void loadFiles()
    {
        //The path of our exectuable
        string exePath = Application.StartupPath;

        //Set our working directory to our exe path for file reading
        Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(exePath);

        string[] aConferences = File.ReadAllLines(@"DATA\CONFERENCES.txt");
        string[] aParticipants = File.ReadAllLines(@"DATA\PARTICIPANTS.txt");
        string[] aType = File.ReadAllLines(@"DATA\TYPE.txt");
        string[] aWkshpReg = File.ReadAllLines(@"DATA\WKSHP_REGISTRATIONS.txt");
        string[] aWorkshops = File.ReadAllLines(@"DATA\WORKSHOPS.txt");

        //Make our arrays jagged for easier processing
        string[][] aConfJag  = aConferences.Select(line => line.Split(',').ToArray()).ToArray();
        string[][] aPartJag  = aParticipants.Select(line => line.Split(',').ToArray()).ToArray();
        string[][] aTypeJag  = aType.Select(line => line.Split(',').ToArray()).ToArray();
        string[][] aWkshpJag = aWkshpReg.Select(line => line.Split(',').ToArray()).ToArray();
        string[][] aWorkJag  = aWorkshops.Select(line => line.Split(',').ToArray()).ToArray();
    }
}
```

And when I try to access the variables from another class they come up as null and it throws an exception.

```
public void updateFormData()
{
    //Participant Type
    var data = new DataFileLoad();
    data.loadFiles();
    foreach(string[] e in data.aTypeJag)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e[1]);
        comboConference.Items.Add(e[1]);
    }
}
```

> ```
> System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
>   HResult=-2147467261
>   Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   Source=FBLA_App
> ```

Is what I get. Thoughts? Not quite sure why i'm getting null variables.

Comment: You are not using the class variables in your loadFiles method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are defining new variables inside the `loadFiles` method.

Do this instead:

```
public class DataFileLoad
{
    //Public jagged array variables
    public string[][] aConfJag = null;
    public string[][] aPartJag = null;
    public string[][] aTypeJag = null;
    public string[][] aWkshpJag = null;
    public string[][] aWorkJag = null;

    public void loadFiles()
    {
        //The path of our exectuable
        string exePath = Application.StartupPath;

        //Set our working directory to our exe path for file reading
        Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(exePath);

        string[] aConferences = File.ReadAllLines(@"DATA\CONFERENCES.txt");
        string[] aParticipants = File.ReadAllLines(@"DATA\PARTICIPANTS.txt");
        string[] aType = File.ReadAllLines(@"DATA\TYPE.txt");
        string[] aWkshpReg = File.ReadAllLines(@"DATA\WKSHP_REGISTRATIONS.txt");
        string[] aWorkshops = File.ReadAllLines(@"DATA\WORKSHOPS.txt");

        //Make our arrays jagged for easier processing
        aConfJag  = aConferences.Select(line => line.Split(',').ToArray()).ToArray();
        aPartJag  = aParticipants.Select(line => line.Split(',').ToArray()).ToArray();
        aTypeJag  = aType.Select(line => line.Split(',').ToArray()).ToArray();
        aWkshpJag = aWkshpReg.Select(line => line.Split(',').ToArray()).ToArray();
        aWorkJag  = aWorkshops.Select(line => line.Split(',').ToArray()).ToArray();
    }
}
```

I would also **strongly recommend** that you do **NOT** expose these variables as is. Encapsulate them in readonly properties instead so that their value cannot be changed from outside the `DataFileLoad` class.

Comment: You are welcome! Don't worry, we've all been there. ;) Don't forget to mark as the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

you're "hiding" the class fields by re-declaring them.  just take off the declaration:

```
    //Make our arrays jagged for easier processing
    aConfJag  = aConferences.Select(line => line.Split(',').ToArray()).ToArray();
    aPartJag  = aParticipants.Select(line => line.Split(',').ToArray()).ToArray();
    aTypeJag  = aType.Select(line => line.Split(',').ToArray()).ToArray();
    aWkshpJag = aWkshpReg.Select(line => line.Split(',').ToArray()).ToArray();
    aWorkJag  = aWorkshops.Select(line => line.Split(',').ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
        string[][] aConfJag  = aConferences.Select(line => line.Split(',').ToArray()).ToArray();
        string[][] aPartJag  = aParticipants.Select(line => line.Split(',').ToArray()).ToArray();
        string[][] aTypeJag  = aType.Select(line => line.Split(',').ToArray()).ToArray();
        string[][] aWkshpJag = aWkshpReg.Select(line => line.Split(',').ToArray()).ToArray();
        string[][] aWorkJag  = aWorkshops.Select(line => line.Split(',').ToArray()).ToArray();
```

to

```
       aConfJag  = aConferences.Select(line => line.Split(',').ToArray()).ToArray();
       aPartJag  = aParticipants.Select(line => line.Split(',').ToArray()).ToArray();
       aTypeJag  = aType.Select(line => line.Split(',').ToArray()).ToArray();
       aWkshpJag = aWkshpReg.Select(line => line.Split(',').ToArray()).ToArray();
       aWorkJag  = aWorkshops.Select(line => line.Split(',').ToArray()).ToArray();
```

You were creating new variable rather than assigning them to you class level variables